# Namespace technique in JavaScript having issues in JSLint

Tags: javascript, namespaces, jslint

I read an article regarding the various ways to [namespace in JavaScript](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/namespacing-in-javascript/). I quite liked the look of the last one but [JSLint](http://www.JSLint.com/) thinks otherwise. I know JSLint can be overzealous but is there a way to make this technique play nice with it?

```
var Something = {};

(function () {
    "use strict";

    this.helloWorld = function () {
        var greeting = "Hello World!";
    };

}.apply(Something));
```

Comment: I do not recommend this technique; it is uncommon enough that you will make whomever's reading your code do a double-take. Unnecessary mental burden. Pattern 3 is by far the most common, at least among those who haven't adopted a proper module system.

Comment: I guess I’ll take your point about it being uncommon. That _can_ be confusing.

Comment: One thing to note is that working with `this` is a pain the the back. I always prefer module definitions that avoid using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var Something = {};

(function (something) {
    "use strict";

    something.helloWorld = function () {
        var greeting = "Hello World!";
    };

}(Something));
```

Comment: Even though I know of this technique, I will mark this as the answer as I guess it answers the original question about JSLint. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use `call` instead of `apply`. `apply` is defined with exactly two parameters (where second one is array of arguments) and `call` really requires only one parameter (namespace) and has list of optional arguments.

Comment: This is false; the second argument is optional for `apply` as well.

Comment: A lot of things are actually optional, but we are talking about JSLint. It has much more strict behaviour that browser interpreters.

Comment: JSLint does not have any bugs relating to requiring unnecessary arguments. You should at least test out your advice before giving it: http://jslint.com/